# adding cookie as a string to phantom page using node.js phantom module

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, setcookie

I have phantom server running which recieves a request with a cookie attached inside header. I have to use this cookie while opening a page from phantom. To be more precise, I have a string that I need to add as a cookie while opening a page. I have installed phantom using node module model(npm install phantom). Below is my code which I'm trying but I cannot see any cookies :

```
phantom.create(function(ph){
   ph.createPage(function (page) {
       console.log(page);
       var cookieAdded = ph.addCookie({
           'name': 'OSF Cookie',
           'value': req.headers.cookie,
           'domain': req.headers.host
       });
       console.log(cookieAdded);
       page.open(url, function (status) {
           if (status == 'success') {
               console.log("Success");
               page.getCookies(function(cookie){
                   console.log(cookie);
               });
               page.evaluate(
                   function () {
                       console.log(document.headers);
                       return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
                   },
                   function (content) {
                       // console.log(content);
                       res.send(content);
                       console.log('RESPONSE SEND')
                       ph.exit();
                   });
           }
           else {
               console.log("Status Failed");
               ph.exit();
           }
       })

   });
});
```

[EDIT]Below is the output :

```
http://localhost:5000/dashboard/
{ url: 'http://localhost:5000/dashboard/' }
osf=5540e22b8f6ac302b117a4cd.DWKdATsCvxskYqL-QfQYSjmYMvI
{ set: [Function],
  get: [Function],
  open: [Function],
  close: [Function],
  includeJs: [Function],
  sendEvent: [Function],
  release: [Function],
  uploadFile: [Function],
  goBack: [Function],
  goForward: [Function],
  reload: [Function],
  switchToFrame: [Function],
  switchToMainFrame: [Function],
  switchToParentFrame: [Function],
  switchToFocusedFrame: [Function],
  onConsoleMessage: [Function],
  onError: [Function],
  onResourceRequested: [Function],
  injectJs: [Function],
  evaluate: [Function],
  render: [Function],
  getContent: [Function],
  getCookies: [Function],
  renderBase64: [Function],
  setHeaders: [Function],
  setContent: [Function],
  setViewportSize: [Function],
  setPaperSize: [Function],
  setZoomFactor: [Function],
  setFileOnPicker: [Function],
  _evaluate: [Function],
  _onResourceRequested: [Function] }
undefined
Success
[]
RESPONSE SEND
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with your issue, but what is `document.headers` supposed to be? To the best of my knowledge, there is not such thing.

Comment: Turns out `phantom.addCookie()` is [implemented](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/blob/12af4a811d3990c5ab83c26caa222e72ec2d6734/shim.js#L5619-L5622).

Comment: Ok ! So after struggling for almost two hours I figured out the way to use addCookie method. But, my original question seems unresolved yet.  How am I supposed to add a string cookie(suppose osf=5540e22b8f6ac302b117a4cd.DWKdATsCvxskYqL-QfQYSjmYMvI) while opening a page? addCookie asks for three things name, value & domain so my guess is I would add this string in value. Am I correct on this?

Comment: name: 'osf', value: '5540e22b8f6ac302b117a4cd.DWKdATsCvxskYqL-QfQYSjmYMvI)'